# How to dealing with huge directory in node?

Tags: node.js

Suppose that I have a directory with millions of files. I want to walk through all the files in the directory with as small memory footprint as possible.

Comment: do you want that recursive or just the files in directory?

Comment: Only one huge folder with lots of files, no recursive.

Comment: did you tried with `fs.readdir`?

Comment: @Mritunjay `fs.readdir` will grab all the filenames and save them in memory, it's slow and memory killing.

Comment: I think Node is designed for more trivial operations, rather than large, memory intensive ones.

Comment: see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/388